# Circle isn't being drawn at the center of the view

Tags: ios, swift, animation, calayer

So I am attempting to draw a circle in the center of a UIView.

```swift
class CircleView: UIView {

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        shapeLayer.path         = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor  = Colors.darkPurple.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor    = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth    = 10
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd    = 0

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
    }

    @objc private func handleTap() {
        print("....Animating Circle....")

        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        basicAnimation.toValue               = 1
        basicAnimation.duration              = 2
        basicAnimation.fillMode              = .forwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "circleAnimation")
    }
}
```

Yet the circle for some reason is being drawn completely at the bottom right corner of the view, even though I've specified that the arcCenter is the view's center.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your centre point .. You View centre point is according to its superview .. thats why your circle was not center of your view

```
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: bounds.midX/2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
```

Better to not fix the radius of your view... make it dynamic .. like i used half of the view ... its related with view size now

Also for drawing circle use line cap to round

```
shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
```

I hope it will help you